# Devise sending email notification after Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, email-notifications

I set `config.send_email_changed_notification = true` in devise's initializer. But after that User's are receiving emails after sign up. It was not supposed to happen, since they did not change their emails, but just created an account. I find in the log that the values were being inserted in the table and after they are being updated. But I did not find why it is happening.

Comment: Please post your log while signup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. the error was because I had a callback that was accidentally updating all the model. I was doing this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_settings

  has_one :setting

  private
    def set_settings
      setting = Setting.create(alert_level: 0)
      self.update_attributes(setting: setting)
    end

end
```

But this callback was updating all the model attributes with same values + the new setting. I changed for:

```
def set_settings
      setting = Setting.create(alert_level: 0)
      self.setting = setting
    end
```

And It worked, just updating this attribute.